# WMF image data validation?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, corruption, wmf

There is an image capturing device which gives its output in wmf. This output is stored in the database directly. We have cases where at times some of these images do not appear on a web page in IE. But if we right click on the page we are able to save the image on to the hard disk; meaning the image does exist on the page, but does not appear visible. I think this is because of some file corruption issue, but I don't know how to resolve it. We are however able to view such files using MS Picture Viewer (desktop app). Is there anyway we can detect such problematic files?

Comment: I've had the exact same problem with IE, but never thought it might be caused by corrupted files. I'd love to see some possible solutions here!

Answer (score 0):

I hope I am not being over simplistic over this but the following function works for me:

```
    public bool IsValidMetaFile(string filePath)
    {
        try
        {
            var metaFile = new Metafile(filePath);

            var metaFileHeader = metaFile.GetMetafileHeader();

            return metaFileHeader.IsWmf() ||
                   metaFileHeader.IsWmfPlaceable() ||
                   metaFileHeader.IsEmf() ||
                   metaFileHeader.IsEmfPlusDual() ||
                   metaFileHeader.IsEmfPlusOnly() ||
                   metaFileHeader.IsEmfOrEmfPlus();
        }
        catch (Exception mesg)
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```